# Android : circular button with an image in the background

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to create a button that is in a circular shape with a custom background
(witch is a circle image)
and is there a way to make it scale depending on the screen size ? (preferably using XML to scale it)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Pauls answer, you can also simply use "dp" in order to make the size of the button density independent. Most phones are 320dp x 360dp.

For more information:
http://mediag.com/news/popular-screen-resolutions-designing-for-all/